# Visual Studio disable spelling check

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-assist

How can I disable spelling check in Visual Studio 2010? By spelling check I mean in comments, string etc, not in actual code

Comment: When you say spelling do you mean as in a dictionary based spell checker? If so it sounds like you have an add-on or similar that you need to disable or uninstall.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Cory** - This will disable syntax highlighting.

This is probably an extension you have installed. You needs to disable it in the extensions manager or configure it not to check spelling.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yardman/archive/2011/02/01/visual-studio-2010-spell-checker.aspx

For example in my install spell checking is provided by Visual Assist. If I disable this extension then the squigglies in comments go away.

Comment: i'm using VA indeed. Is there a way to turn this off in VA option?

Comment: As an Update the option now is directly in Menu Bar|VASSISTX|Visual Assist X Options...|Underlines

Answer (score 20):

In the Visual Assist X Options dialog on the `Underlines` page, uncheck the "Underline spelling errors in comments and strings" option.

Answer (score 9):

I'm fairly certain VS2010 doesn't have a built in spell-checker, however, the C/C++ options contain IntelliSense which can cause "red squiggles." Here's how to disable those:

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced

Under "IntelliSense" will be an option called "Disable Squiggles." Set it to true.

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem in Visual Studio 2019. Turned out it was my Resharper extension. Extensions->Resparper->Options->Tools->Respeller->Enable Respeller (uncheck)

Answer (score 0):

in javascript I solved this by going to Tools > Options > TextEditor > Javascript > advanced > Uncheck Show Syntax Errors.

Comment: You are a genius.