# How to tun off "spell-check" in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, spell-checking

[image]

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Update 3,

How do I turn off spell checker, its irritating for me.

Anyone knows about it then please tell me.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114557/visual-studio-disable-spelling-check

Comment: I do not believe VS has spell checker built in, most likely you are using an extension.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas ok, do you know how to disable it? Thanks

Comment: @JesseJames no, I don't know about it. Thanks

Comment: @Ahmedilyas I have not downloaded that extention, "Spell Checker". Still I am getting it.

Comment: Please show a screenshot of what you mean, or copy and paste a message it gives you. If you mean compiler messages, you actually need to fix your code, you can't make those go away.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have installed "ComponentOne" library. Does it affect it? see my screen shot. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

check **Tools** | **Extensions and Updates** and see which extension are listed.  If spell checker is there, remove it and see if you still get spell checking.If so, something else is doing it.

Comment: I have checked it, but not installed "Spell checking". @Midhun

Comment: may name of extension will be different like "visual studio Spell Checker" like this

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have found the way.

I have installed "**ComponentOne IntelliSpell for Visual Studio**",

So, I just **Uninstalled** it and evrything works well!!

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below simple steps:

1. Go to Tools > Extensions and Updates
2. In Search, type "*Spell Checker*" or "*Visual Studio Spell Checker*"
3. Select the tool and you can **Disable** or **Uninstall**

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoteR.png) to see the screenshot