# Visual Studio 2022 how to disable spellcheck?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Today I updated my (Windows 10) PC and started my day noticing a lot of green squiggly lines telling me all sort of weird things like how words like Perform and Vehicle aren't real words

[image]

Which is slowly driving me nuts.

If I try to search under tools > options (or under feature search) for things like *spell*, *spelling*, *spell check*, *spellcheck* I am told there are no such results. If I google it I get results like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/676713/visual-studio-2022-spell-checker-settings-and-cont)
telling me it's a preview feature that's not available (but being developed) leading me to believe it's under Preview Features. But Santa Clausing that list leads me nowhere. I also get a link a spellcheck extension, a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114557/visual-studio-disable-spelling-check) about VS2010 filled with non-solutions. I have [no spell checking extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxFOS.png) installed either.

So, how do I get rid of it? It checks most things. From variable names to function names, to strings and the links I use for HTTP requests and I just want it to stop

Comment: It may be available as a color, in which case you may be able to set it to match the background color.

Comment: Found this setting: ```[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\RemoteSettings\devenv\17.5.33209.295\d17.5\FeatureFlags]
"Editor.EnableSpellChecker"=dword:00000000
``` The weird thing is - VS always overwrites the dword to 00000001 :-( This is soo annoying that I am switching to release VS 2022. Shame on you MS!

Comment: I assume that you are on 17.5 Preview 2. That was fixed on Preview 3 which was released today. So please upgrade.  You can disable Spell Checking through 3 ways:
-. Search for "Spell" in Tools.. Options and disable it
-. There is a new toolbar button and menu items for that (Feature Search or Ctrl+Q it)
-. In the LightBulb menu there is an option to disable it
I hope this helps..

Comment: @JoseParra bless you but it worked. I updated to preview 3 and not only was there an option for spell check, and it's off by default!

Comment: Wow this is annoying.  Anyone who actually builds code knows that there are simply not  enough words to spell them all correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @JoseParra's suggestion, all I had to do to fix this was update from preview 2 to preview 3

Answer (score 4):

Just do a mouseover on the squiggly lines and click the bulb.

There you can disable spellchecking.

[image]

Comment: I weren't able to do that. This was a bug in VS2022 17.5 Preview 2 (I couldn't disable spellcheck) that got resolved when I updated to Preview 3

Comment: @Ja Da: Ok, I see. I was looking for a way to disable the spellchecker myself and found your question. Then when I figured out how to disable the spellchecker I posted this answer in case others are looking for it.

Comment: I wish I had such an option in my VS2022 17.7.1. Since I'd like to use ReSharper ReSpeller instead. And "Toggle Spell Checker" button doesn't work.